# How can I assign a value to the diagonals of a 4-D matrix using linear indexing in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix, variable-assignment, diagonal

I have a 4-D matrix `A` of size `NxNxPxQ`. How can I easily change the diagonal values to 1 for each `NxN` 2-D submatrix in a vectorized way?

Answer (score 3):

Incorporating gnovice's suggestion, an easy way to index the elements is:

```
[N,~,P,Q]=size(A);%# get dimensions of your matrix

diagIndex=repmat(logical(eye(N)),[1 1 P Q]);%# get logical indices of the diagonals    
A(diagIndex)=1;%# now index your matrix and set the diagonals to 1.
```

Comment: You can actually avoid the need for using FIND by creating the identity matrix as a logical matrix, then doing logical indexing: `diagIndex = repmat(logical(eye(dim1)),[1 1 dim3 dim4]);`

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this very simply by directly computing the linear indices for every diagonal element, then setting them to 1:

```
[N,N,P,Q] = size(A);
diagIndex = cumsum([1:(N+1):N^2; N^2.*ones(P*Q-1,N)]);
A(diagIndex) = 1;
```

The above example finds the `N` diagonal indices for the first `N`-by-`N` matrix (`1:(N+1):N^2`). Each subsequent `N`-by-`N` matrix (`P*Q-1` of them) is offset by `N^2` elements from the last, so a matrix of size `PQ-1`-by-`N` containing only the value `N^2` is appended to the linear indices for the diagonal of the first matrix. When a cumulative sum is performed over each column using the function [CUMSUM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html), the resulting matrix contains the linear indices for all diagonal elements of the 4-D matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct indexing, and some faffing about with repmat, to add the indexes for a single 50x50 diagonal to the offsets within the larger matrix of each 50x50 block:

Here's an example for a smaller problem:

```
A = NaN(10,10,5,3);
inner = repmat(sub2ind([10 10], [1:10],[1:10]), 5*3, 10); % diagonals
outer = repmat([10*10 * [0:5*3-1]]', 1, 10*10); % offsets to blocks
diags = inner + outer;
A(diags(:)) = 1;
```