# How can I index the diagonals of a 3-D matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, indexing, multidimensional-array, matrix, diagonal

I have an M-by-M-by-N matrix, which is a concatenation of N M-by-M matrices. I want to reduce this matrix to an M-by-N matrix by taking the diagonals of each M-by-M submatrix and concatenating them together. How can I do this in a simple vectorized way?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I'd answered something like this before, but it took me some time to find it: [changing diagonals to 1 in a 4 dimensional matrix in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319178/changing-diagonals-to-1-in-a-4-dimensional-matrix-in-matlab). Although there are slight differences (assignment versus indexing, 3-D versus 4-D), the answers are general enough that the questions could probably be considered duplicates. Perhaps a refinement of the titles and tags are in order to make these easier to find (I find myself saying that a lot lately).

Comment: A lot of the questions are described in terms of the asker's needs (e.g., how can I calculate the concentration from the blah blah), but are in essence, matrix manipulation questions. I'd propose cleaning them up later after the asker is satisfied, to make it more general (i.e., strip off the specific needs and trim it to bare bones). That would in fact help people searching for answers find them more easily and hopefully, reduce dupes, because in most cases, the confusion is because of the way the question is worded.

Comment: @R. M.: I've already made some edits so that the titles and tags are clearer and will hopefully make these show up better in searches for this sort of matrix manipulation question.

Comment: @R. M., gnovice: From a questioner's view, esp. someone who is new to Matlab and linear algebra like me, how can I recognize the hidden topics in my questions? Put it another way, how can I recognize which of the basic matrix manipulation operations can be used to achieve my goal? Many thanks

Comment: if you read the first version of the question, you'll see that the gist was "how to pick the diagonals of a 3D `MxNxN` matrix", and that would've been a more accurate title than "how to reduce dimensions", which could also mean reducing from `MxN` to some `MxK` or `LxK`, and hence is ambiguous. As for what matrix manipulations to use, that comes from practice and SO is a perfectly fine place to ask such questions. What gnovice and I were talking about was re: editing questions to make it more general and easy for a newcomer to search and find answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by getting the linear indices of the diagonals and using it to form a new matrix

```
[M,~,N]=size(A);%# A is your matrix
indx=cumsum([1:(M+1):M^2; M^2.*ones(N-1,M)]);%#diagonal indices

B=A(indx');%'# transpose to get MxN
```

In the above, I've used `~` to disregard that output from the function. However, this works only if you're using MATLAB R2009b and above. If your version is older than that, use a dummy variable instead.